# LVM can I extend a logical volume across 2 volume groups?

Tags: lvm, partition

I resized my `/opt` which was the only logical vol in vg2 but I want to give that freed space back to `/` which is on vg1.  Is this possible?  pvscan output below.  I want to grow my `/` partition which is on vg1 by 200 GB.

```
PV /dev/sda3   VG vg2   lvm2 [212.40 GiB / 202.40 GiB free]
PV /dev/sda2   VG vg1   lvm2 [537.10 GiB / 0          free]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no.

You cannot extend LV's across multiple Volume Groups.

Instead, you should have added all PV's to the same VG. This gives you way more flexibility when it comes to managing the disk space allocation.

Comment: Can I delete VG2 and merge the space into VG1 and then recreate /opt under vg1?

Comment: Yes. 'vgextend vg1 /dev/sda3'